# Overlapping Div Elements

Tags: html, css, overlapping

I'm making my own portfolio these days and I want to add a contact form on it. I tried it but the div is overlapping to footer like this. Can anyone help me to fix this? Thank you so much.

[image]

```css
#contactus {height: 105vh; margin:0 auto;}

#formContainer{ width: 85%;  margin: 0 auto; background-color: aqua;   }

.contactHead{ text-align: center}
```

```html
<div id="contactus">
 
 <div id="formContainer">
  <h1 class="contactHead">Get In Touch!</h1>
  <h4 class="contactHead">I will be with you within 24 hours</h4>
  
  <form id="contactForm">
  <input type="text" id="nameContainer" placeholder="Name">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="email" id="emailContainer" placeholder="Email Address">
   
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="messageContainer" placeholder="Message">
   
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
  </form>
  
 </div>
 
</div>
```

fV.png

Comment: could you please add your footer too to your code, I can't see it.. also the image is 404... make sure you create a complete, verifiable problem in your question :)

Comment: hi could you please look at the below answer from Kevin and run code snippet? there you can see the problem

Comment: in Kevin's code, the issue is `height: 105vh` and `margin: 0 auto -80px` styles - try removing them and check... and I don't know why the height and negative margin there...

Comment: Thank you very much kukkuz. It is working. I have another one to ask. What should I add to make the parent tag height? Padding top and bottm?

Comment: You are trying to *extend* the `contactus` div till the footer whatever the page height?

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it could help.

Your Image is not loading.

[image]

```css
#contactus {
    
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#formContainer{ width: 85%;  margin: 0 auto; background-color: aqua;   }

.contactHead{ text-align: center}

.footer{
  height:250px;
  background-color:#1e1e1e;
  text-align:center;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.footer h2{
  
  color: #fff;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="contactus">
 
 <div id="formContainer">
  <h1 class="contactHead">Get In Touch!</h1>
  <h4 class="contactHead">I will be with you within 24 hours</h4>
  
  <form id="contactForm">
  <input type="text" id="nameContainer" placeholder="Name">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="email" id="emailContainer" placeholder="Email Address">
   
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="messageContainer" placeholder="Message">
   
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
  </form>
  
 </div>
 
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin. But the problem still remains. When I run your code, There is also the problem what I want to slove

Comment: can you share in details what are the issue you are facing?